# how to get proxy from string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have string

```
76.125.85.66:16805 | 0.238 | Little Rock | AR | Unknown | United
States69.207.212.76:49233 | 0.274 | Sayre | PA | 18840 | United 
States96.42.127.190:25480 | 0.292 | Sartell | MN | 56377 | United States
```

and heres how I get proxy from it
my code

```
Dim ip As String = "76.125.85.66:16805 | 0.238 | Little Rock | AR | Unknown | United States69.207.212.76:49233 | 0.274 | Sayre | PA | 18840 | United States96.42.127.190:25480 | 0.292 | Sartell | MN | 56377 | United States"
    ip = Regex.Match(ip, "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\:\d{2,5}\b", RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString
    RichTextBox1.Text = ip
```

it only show first proxy 76.125.85.66:16805 but i want it show all

`76.125.85.66:16805`

`69.207.212.76:49233`

`96.42.127.190:25480`

Comment: ?? Will this do it `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d*` ??, Only use `Matches` Not `Match`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Regex**.[`Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead and remove the beginning word boundary.

You could write it as follows:

```
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(ip, "(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d+")
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/IOxKxP)

Answer (score -1):

use this pattern to return multi result for specific expression

```cs
public ArrayList HRefs(string incomingHtml)
    {
      ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
      string pattern = "href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"(?<1>[^\"]*)\"|(?<1>\\S+))";
      for (Match match = Regex.Match(incomingHtml, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
      {
        string str = match.Groups[1].Value;
        arrayList.Add(str);
      }
      return arrayList;
    }
```

Comment: That pattern has nothing to do with the string??

Comment: I'm saying OP is trying to match the IP/Proxies in the string, not href tags of any sort.

Comment: this is not the idea, the idea was to find multi result by patten, his code find only one result...